# auto SUM with javascript in php looping

Tags: php, javascript, html

i'm trying to calculate value on listbox, but my code didn't work
this is my javascript code :

```
var val=document.getElementById('inh').value;
var temp=val.split("");

   function sum(){
    var val = document.getElementById('inh').value;
    var temp = val.split(" ");

    var total = 0;
    var v;
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        v = parseFloat(temp[i]);
        if (!isNaN(v)) total += v;
    }

    document.getElementById('resultSum').innerHTML=total;

}
```

this is the html code :

```
<label for="ttotal"></label>
        <input type="text" name="ttotal" id="ttotal"  onkeyup="sum()"  />
```

and

```
  <select name="inh[<?php echo $no; ?>]">
     <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>1 tablet</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>2 tablet</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>3 tablet</option>
  </select>
```

thank's

Comment: `document.getElementById('inh')` should be `null` because there's no element with an `id` of "inh"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here.. You have no element that has `id=inh` in your HTML

Comment: i'm a newbie, please help me
i've add id on listbox inh, so what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

### Replace

```
<input type="text" name="ttotal" id="ttotal"  onkeyup="sum()"  />
```

### with this:

```
<input type="text" name="ttotal" id="ttotal"  onkeyup="sum('[<?php echo $no; ?>]')"  />
```

### Javascript function

```
function sum( el ){
    var val = document.getElementById( el ).value;
    var temp = val.split(" ");

    var total = 0;
    var v;
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        v = parseFloat(temp[i]);
        if (!isNaN(v)) total += v;
    }

    document.getElementById('resultSum').innerHTML=total;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i have change my code like your instuction, but it didn't work...

Comment: What did not work? It worked for me. Can you share your new code in a fiddle?

Comment: Can you do a `alert(el)` inside the function `sum`?. Want to check if we are getting a value..

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum( el ){ var val = document.getElementById( el ).value;
 var temp = val.split(" ");
 var total = 0; 
var v;
 for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
 v = parseFloat(temp[i]); 
if (!isNaN(v)) total += v;
 }
 document.getElementById('resultSum').innerHTML=total; 
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="ttotal" id="ttotal" onkeyup="sum('[<?php echo $no; ?>]')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

my code did work, but when i change my choice on listbox, it didn't calculate new change
why ?

```
function jumlah(n){
    var nilai = 0;
        for( var i = 1; i<=n; i++ )
        {
            var a = document.getElementById("inh["+i+"]");
                if(a.value != "")
            {
                nilai = nilai + parseInt(a.value);
            }
        }
        //alert(n);
        document.getElementById("txtjumlah").value = nilai;
        //alert(nilai);
    }
```

this is LISTBOX :

```
<select name="inh[<?php echo $no; ?>]" id="inh[<?php echo $no; ?>]" onchange="jumlah(<?php echo $count; ?>);">
            <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>1 tablet</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>2 tablet</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if($datatampil['dosis_inh_perhari']==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>3 tablet</option>
          </select>
```

and this is text for output calculated data :

```
<input type="text" name="txtjumlah" id="txtjumlah" value="" readonly="readonly" style="width:30px;" />
```

thank's for your help :)